# Podman Ps Format help

Tags: bash, docker, container, podman

I am trying to list `podman ps`  in a very readable format using `podman ps -a --format="ID\t{{.ID}}\nNAME\t{{.Names}}\nIMAGE\t{{.Image}}\nPORTS\t{{.Ports}}\nCOMMAND\t{{.Command}}\nCREATED\t{{.CreatedAt}}\nSTATUS\t{{.Status}}\n"` but `\n` i.e. newline is not rendered as expected.

I am trying this in a linux debian 11.

The result is as follows:

```bash
ID      39b1e13k1750\nNAME  suspicious_wi\nIMAGE  nginx\nPORTS  \nCOMMAND  nginx -g daemon o...\nCREATED  2022-08-08 08:23:43.1437658 +0200 CEST\nSTATUS  Exited (0) 40 minutes ago\n
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Podman in Debian 11 doesn’t process `\n` in its format templates; they can however be represented as Go strings in the template (`{{"\n"}}`):

```
podman ps -a --format='ID\t{{.ID}}{{"\n"}}NAME\t{{.Names}}{{"\n"}}IMAGE\t{{.Image}}{{"\n"}}PORTS\t{{.Ports}}{{"\n"}}COMMAND\t{{.Command}}{{"\n"}}CREATED\t{{.CreatedAt}}{{"\n"}}STATUS\t{{.Status}}'
```